# Include CSRF in Select2 Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

**I have include csrf in data ajax, but its always not allowed.**

what should i do to pass the csrf ?

```
var csrfName = $('.txt_csrfname').attr('name'); 
var csrfHash = $('.txt_csrfname').val(); // CSRF hash
$("#selPerguruan").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>user/pendidikan/get_perguruan',
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 10,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params.term,
                csrfName: csrfHash
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: do you get any error in console ?

Comment: i got erorr forbidden 403